# AWS API Gateway custom domain path propagation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I Recently added a custom domain to an existing microservice api in API Gateway. Lets say the microservice api is for the Foo-service and already has a path called `/foo`. I defined a base path mapping for my custom domain which maps the path `/foo` to the Foo-service api.

However when I now want to call the `/foo` endpoint of the Foo-service, using my custom domain, the url becomes `www.example.com/foo/foo` which makes sense, however I would prefer to just call `www.example.com/foo` with the same result. Is there some way to make my custom domain propagate the path? I would rather not change either the base path mapping of the custom domain or the `/foo` path of my Foo-service. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No, i'm pretty sure it can't be done in an acceptable way. I did end up renaming the base path for my foo-service API from /foo to just /.